# Android Java and PHP encryption (AES) mismatch

Tags: php, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I have this line of code:

```
$signature = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($signature), 'AES-256-CBC', $apiKey->private_key, 0, $iv);
```

And in my Android application I have this:

```
public String encrypt(String message, String privateKey) throws Exception{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec iv = makeIv();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(privateKey), iv);
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

And when I encrypt something in Java and send it to PHP, there, I get different output from decryption following with signature check failure.

What is the right way to encrypt on `Java/Android` side so that I can decrypt it in PHP like the line above shows?

Note: Do not worry about IV as I have a mechanism of exchanging it so I am using the same one for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Well, how does the output differ from the expected output? Has it the same length? Are some of the bytes the same and some different (which ones)? Are the completely different? How long is your input (in bytes)?

Comment: I have never, printed output PHP, I assumed it is wrong, but now when check openssl_decrypt, it returns FALSE with this error: ```error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length```

Comment: Hmmm could you show us the makeKey() function?

Comment: ```private Key makeKey(String key) { return new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES"); }```